# Getting `execve failed: No such file or directory` when calling `boost::process::system()` with separate arguments

Tags: c++, boost, process

If  I call it with one whole hardcoded commands, it works, but when I separate the arguments, it throws:

> execve failed: No such file or directory

Running the example [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_process/design.html#boost_process.design.arg_cmd_style):

```cpp
bp::system("grep -c false /etc/passwd"); // ok
bp::system("grep", "-c", "false", "/etc/passwd"); // fails

bp::system(cmd="grep -c false /etc/passwd"); // ok
bp::system(exe="grep", args={"-c", "false", "/etc/passwd"}); // fails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it does not check the `PATH` when using the `exe-args style`:

> If a single string (or the explicit form bp::cmd), it will be interpreted as a command line. That will cause the execution function to search the PATH variable to find the executable. The alternative is the exe-args style, where the first string will be interpreted as a filename (including the path), and the rest as arguments passed to said function.

It works with `full path`:

```cpp
bp::system("/bin/grep", "-c", "false", "/etc/passwd");
```